# Identifier not found with a function in Opencv, how to solve this?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, image-processing, noise-reduction

I'm trying to use this function:

> fastNlMeansDenoising(image, image, 3.0, 7, 21);

Using OpenCV with Visual Studio 2010 express, but it said "identifier not found".
I did a quick search and found that this must be a ".lib" is missing, but I did not find which library should I add in my project for this function to work. Anyone could help me with this?

Comment: Identifier not found is a compilation error. 1. Check if the library header files are in the additional include headers path. 2. Check if you have included the required header where the function declaration is.

Comment: 1. Checked! 2. I have no idea what is the required header for this function.

Comment: ctrl-shift-f  fastNlMeansDenoising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to use opencv 2.4.9, it is not available in 2.3.0

Answer (score 2):

Ok. In order to use `fastNlMeansDenoising(image, image, 3.0, 7, 21);`

1) You need to configure opencv 2.4.8 or 2.4.9.

Here is procedure to [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-VgWxkVp2w) opencv 249 with Visual studio.

2) Use the following code to test opencv function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
   // load the image

   Mat img = imread("lenna.jpg");


   if(!img.data) 
   {
      cout << "File not found" << endl;
      return -1;
   }

   // show it in a window
   namedWindow( "Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   imshow("Image", img);

   // image window will immediately disappear if the program ends, so
   // we'll wait for a keypress, indefinitely
   waitKey();

   // do a simple transformation: convert to grayscale

   // first copy the image
   Mat img_gray = img.clone();
   Mat img1;
   cvtColor(img, img_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
   fastNlMeansDenoising(img_gray,img1,3.0,7,21);
   imshow("Image", img1);
   waitKey();
   return 0;
}
```

Hope, this helps you.
Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

The function is defined in the **photo.hpp** file. So you have to get the **opencv_photo300.lib**

Edit 1:

I searched a little bit (sorry im at work, dont have more time) and i couldnt find the library itself. You can go ahead and build opencv yourself from: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv
Then you can just search that folder for the lib.
An installationguide for the build process is here: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html

Edit 2:

Berak is right, the opencv_photo300.lib is not in the 2.3 Version of OpenCV. Update your OpenCV to the current version 2.4.9 and you'll have what you need.

Comment: I don't have the file in my OpenCV folder. I'm using OpenCV 2.3. Do you know where I can find it?